# Can there be two oozie workflow.xml files in one directory?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Can there be two oozie workflow.xml files in one directory?

If so how can I instruct oozie runner which one to run?

Answer (score 9):

You can have two workflow files (just give them unique names), then you can select which one to call by setting the `oozie.wf.application.path` value in your config file:

```
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://namenode:9000/path/to/job/wf-1.xml
#oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://namenode:9000/path/to/job/wf-2.xml
```

Comment: I'll get back to this problem in a few days...once I try it out I'll change the answer status accordingly...thanks

Comment: It has worked for me. i just created 2 config files too, to set above properties(with different name) and submitted job as per config required for each workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 different directories.

But if you need to call the second workflow file as a sub-workflow just give it a different name. Here is how I call a sub workflow:

I have 2 files in a directory

```
workflow.xml
export.xml
```

And here is how my sub workflow is called from the main one:

```
<action name="export">
    <sub-workflow>
        <app-path>${export_application_path}</app-path>
        <propagate-configuration/>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>exportDir</name>
                <value>${inputSqoop}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </sub-workflow>

    <ok to="cleanup"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>
```

See the explanation in the docs:
http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action