# how to link two workflows in a single coordinator

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

i have two Workflow XML files such as WF1 WF2. Can I link all these workflows in a single co-ordinator for the below actions? WF1 is Time dependent WF2  is No Dependency of anything.i want to execute after completion of one workflow next one to be execute in a single coordinator

Comment: Then make WF2 a **sub-workflow** of WF. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to go forward is to use a **subworkflow** in Oozie; for details see: [Sub-workflow_Action](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action).

A similar question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008745/can-there-be-two-oozie-workflow-xml-files-in-one-directory).